# Angular momentum of a rolling sphere in relation to axis

Tags: angular-momentum, conservation-laws, friction

This might be an old question but I can't seem to find a satisfactory answer.
  Suppose I pushed a sphere with for a certain amount of time and let it roll across a rough surface. Disregarding deformations and air resistance etc., it will **roll without slipping ** with a constant angular velocity( or will it?). And I will include only the sphere in my system of interest.
  If I choose the contact point as the axis, everything is fine : there's no net external torque because position vector is zero, and angular momentum is conserved. However, if I chose the center of mass of the sphere as the axis, the friction force ( seems to ) exert a net torque on the system and the sphere should change angular velocity.
  Where did it went wrong? That is my question. Is there some fictitious(or real) forces that I'm missing?
   I am completely new here so if there is some mistakes I made, I sincerely apologise. And thanks in advance!

Comment: I think I got it. Kinetic friction disappear when there is no relative motion between the surface and the sphere. And static frition will not appear unless there is another external force acting upon the sphere. Can someone varify this please?